# Transform Access Row into Access Field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to replicate the Transform paste from Excel using Access.

I want to select my columns (varying amounts) in Excel.
Paste them into an Access database Table1 row.
The table has 255 fields (in order to accommodate the varying number of columns)

e.g.:
Title, FirstName, Surname, Add1, Add2, Add3, Add4, Town, County, Postcode

What I want is to transform this into a single field of Table2, e.g.:
Table2
Field1
Title
FirstName
Surname
Add1
Add2
Add3
Add4
Town
County
Postcode

I could achieve this by creating an append query for each of the 255 fields in Table1 but that seems ridiculous!

Surely there is a function that could loop through the Table1 and paste them into Table2

Is this at all possible? The easiest thing would be to "Transform" the data whilst still in the Excel file but I wanted to build this ability to aid the functionality of my Access process.

I've tried to use a crosstab query but I am struggling to get the right results.

Comment: Try cross join query maybe? It can provide quite same functionality

Comment: A CROSSTAB is not appropriate nor do I see how a cross join would accomplish. A UNION can rearrange fields but limited to 50 SELECT lines. Only real option is a VBA procedure to run append actions. Open recordset object, loop through fields inside a loop of records. Why would you want all data in 1 field? If there are multiple records transformed, how will data retain association? Need a group identifier field.

Comment: I need to link my results with a table to find references. The Union solution is the best solution. I have Unionised the first 40 fields (anything more states that it's too complex) then 41 to 80 and then Unionised these two Union Queries. I am assuming I will be able to then Union 81 to 120 and 121 to 160 ultimately up     to 255. Thanks for this. The vba is too complex for me I'm afraid.